# Do I need to have an IP log on my website?

Tags: logging, ip, tracking

Well, this question might be weird, and my english isn't good but still I want to ask: Why does the big sites logs our IP addresses, pages we visited, how long we stayed on a page, etc? I mean, I know that this can be useful if you want to locate an IP that you assume that the user behind it is breaking the law or might be in danger, but that's the only useful cases that I can imagine. the rest is just tracking and following and collecting data for advertisment. but not all of these sites does not contain ads.

For example: Sites like duckduckgo. it might log my IP (I guess they do), but they say that they don't track or follow me. Instead, Other sites can track and follow me even if I don't use them.

All this tracking, What is it good for? and... If I own a website (or app), do I need to track my users too?

Comment: They do not contains add, that doesn't mean they can't sell your informations, you know ? It also helps them understanding their customer's behaviour, wich kind of sites they like, etc, so they can adapt their own to what works the best, as for your last question it depends on your own needs, you probably won't need to track everything if you just want to adapt your site to what your customers will like the best, on the other hand if you want to sell their informations/both, you'll track absolutely everything you can.

Comment: @xoxel yes but what can they do with this? I mean if not to target ads

Comment: Well, i edited my comment, can't think about any other reasons now than those: Adapting, Selling, Advertising. By experience i can say that they all tend to do the adapt part at the very least.